# Grails channel security causing a redirect loop

Tags: grails, spring-security, https, grails-plugin, redirect-loop

I am new to Grails and I am working on an exisiting application. I am trying to force the anyone using our website to allways be on https. I added the Spring Security Core plugin

```
//BuildConfig.groovy
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"
```

and I just added

```
///Config.groovy
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
    '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
```

When I try to go on localhost:8080/myapp, it redirects me to https://localhost:8443/myapp, but I get a "This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" message.

I added print statements in my SecurityFilters.groovy, and I can see the infinite loop going

```
baseFilter(controller: "*", action: "*") 
    {
        before = {  
            println "baseFilter"
            // If auth controller then ok to continue
            if (controllerName.equals("auth"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // If no subject (user) and not auth controller then user must authenticate
            if (!session.subject && !(controllerName.equals("auth")))
            {
              params.targetUri = request.forwardURI - request.contextPath
              if (params.action=="profile") {
                params.targetUri=params.targetUri + "?page=" + params?.page
              }
              else if (params.action=="results") {
                params.targetUri="/home"
              }
              println "baseFilter: Redirecting: PARAMS = $params"
              redirect(controller:'auth', action:'login', params: params)
              return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's just:

```
baseFilter
baseFilter: Redirecting: PARAMS = [action:auth, format:null,  controller:login, targetUri:/login/auth]
```

Over and over.

I've tried many other things I found on Stackoverflow and other websites, but they either do not work, or are too complicated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check your `grails.serverURL` setting. Make sure it's set to use `https` in your `Config.groovy`

Comment: There are is no grails.serverURL setting. I added grails.serverURL = "[https://localhost:8443/myapp](https://localhost:8443/myapp)", but still I get the same error.

Comment: Are you running the app on https ?

Comment: Trying using this setting in dev grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = false

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts I am running with the -https parameter. I tried that useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity setting, but I still get the redirect error.

Comment: I think part of the problem is you are making everything go thru secure channel. There is a possibility that there is some URL which is running un secured and that's why it keeps redirecting.   Try explicit url which you want to secure instead of doing a blanket /**.  There is one more setting which I had  grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443  See if that works

Comment: I now have the following settings on my Config.groovy

grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 8443

grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [

   '/login/': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',

   '/login/auth': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'

]

             but I still get the same issue.

Comment: After setting this what are URL Are you accessing ?

Comment: I tried both [https://localhost:8443/myapp](https://localhost:8443/myapp) and [http://localhost:8080/myapp](http://localhost:8080/myapp). When I try the second one, it redirects me to the first one, but I get the error message.

Comment: How did you run your app? Is it using grails run-app?

Comment: @qusyairi 'grails run-app -https'

Comment: Hi, do you really need to have SecurityFilters.groovy? or is it just a pseudo code to test around? the reason you have lots of reprinted statements is that others assets (images or css & js) were loaded using the server url and it is using the SecurityFilters logic along with it. Maybe a more specific url in the filter would do for your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this isn't the answer to the question, but I managed to achieve what I was trying to do, which was to force SLL, and redirect any attempts to use http. I did this by using the shiro plugin, which was already being used by my application. In the Buildconfig.groovy, just add compile ":shiro:1.2.1" to you plugins. In the config.groovy I added the following properties:

```
security { 
    shiro { 
        filter { 
            loginUrl = "/login" 
            successUrl = "/" 
            unauthorizedUrl = "/unauthorized" 
            filterChainDefinitions = """
                                     /** = ssl[443]
                                     """ 
        } 
    } 
}
```

You can modify your filterChainDefinitions  to only force ssl on certain urls. I just used /** because I always want SSL.